# How do I compare all open Pull Requests in a github repo for conflicts with each other?

Tags: git, github

I'm working with an online video game repo. (Space Station 13) and there are multiple open pull requests that often get tested together based on things like 'balance' and 'fun'.

When loading up Test Merges, conflicts often arise between them and all our compiler is able to tell us is the last one that conflicts with the rest.

What I would like is a way of comparing every pull request with every other pull request.

Although I know it's possible to checkout each pull request and rebase one onto master then rebase the other onto the first. This process is laborious.

We've got access to and often use GitKraken. Is there a better solution to this beyond manually rebasing?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020-04-20, a support ticket to github reveals that there is no such tool, nor do they have a method of performing this task.